# Moving ListViewItems Up & Down

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a ListView (WinForms) in which i want to move items up and down with the click of a button. The items to be moved are the ones who are checked. So if item 2, 6 and 9 are selected, they will become 1, 5 and 8 when I press the button for movement upwards and the items that were on those places are moved down a step.

I feel that I have made this unnecessarily complicated, as you can see below. The second SubItem of each ListViewItem is a number which represents its place in the list (starts on 1).

I blame lack of sleep and coffee for the following code, but if you could figure out a simpler way to complete this task I would be thankful.

```
private void sourceMoveUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Int32> affectedNumbers = new List<Int32>();
        bool foundNonChecked = false;

        List<KeyValuePair<int, ListViewItem>> newList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, ListViewItem>>();

        foreach (ListViewItem item in this.sourceListView.CheckedItems)
        {
            int newNum = int.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text) - 1;

            if (newNum >= 1)
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem testItem in this.sourceListView.Items)
                {
                    if (int.Parse(testItem.SubItems[1].Text) == newNum && !testItem.Checked)
                    {
                        foundNonChecked = true;
                    }
                }

                if (foundNonChecked)
                {
                    item.SubItems[1].Text = newNum.ToString();
                    affectedNumbers.Add(newNum);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (ListViewItem item in this.sourceListView.Items)
        {
            int num = int.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text);

            if (affectedNumbers.Contains(num) && !item.Checked)
            {
                item.SubItems[1].Text = (num + affectedNumbers.Count).ToString();
            }

            newList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, ListViewItem>(int.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text), item));
            item.Remove();
        }

        newList.Sort((firstPair, secondPair) =>
            {
                return firstPair.Key.CompareTo(secondPair.Key);
            }
        );

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ListViewItem> pair in newList)
        {
            this.sourceListView.Items.Add(pair.Value);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
I have shorted it down to the following:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in this.sourceListView.CheckedItems)
        {
            if (item.Index > 0)
            {
                int newIndex = item.Index - 1;
                this.sourceListView.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                this.sourceListView.Items.Insert(newIndex, item);
            }
        }

        int index = 1;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in this.sourceListView.Items)
        {
            item.SubItems[1].Text = index.ToString();

            index++;
        }
```

But now, if I select the two topmost items (or similar) they will switch place when I click the button for upwards movement.

**SECOND EDIT**
Everything works fine for upwards movement with the following:

```
if (this.sourceListView.CheckedItems[0].Index != 0)
        {
            this.sourceListView.BeginUpdate();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in this.sourceListView.CheckedItems)
            {
                if (item.Index > 0)
                {
                    int newIndex = item.Index - 1;
                    this.sourceListView.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                    this.sourceListView.Items.Insert(newIndex, item);
                }
            }

            this.updateListIndexText();

            this.sourceListView.EndUpdate();
        }
```

But for downward movement I can't seem to get it right:

```
if (this.sourceListView.CheckedItems[this.sourceListView.CheckedItems.Count - 1].Index < this.sourceListView.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            this.sourceListView.BeginUpdate();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in this.sourceListView.CheckedItems)
            {
                if (item.Index < this.sourceListView.Items.Count - 1)
                {
                    int newIndex = item.Index + 1;
                    this.sourceListView.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                    this.sourceListView.Items.Insert(newIndex, item);
                }
            }

            this.updateListIndexText();

            this.sourceListView.EndUpdate();
        }
```

It works for moving single items down, but when I select more than one, it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like the top two items is an edge case. Since you are ignoring the first item (index > 0). Add another condition to that if statement: if (item.Index > 0 && !(item.Index == 1 && this.sourceListView.Items[0].Checked)

Comment: what do you want to happen when you checked item 1 & 3 and clicked UP button? If your answer is 1 should remain at top and 3 should move to 2, then I would suggest something simpler, simpler to code simpler for users to understand. If item 1 & 3 are checked and user clicks UP nothing should happen. That's because all items checked should be considered a group and they move UP/Down in a group so if first item can't be moved Up no other can.

Comment: @Charlie, If i select the three topmost items, then item 2 & 3 will switch places. For each checked item (first loop) i could have a loop that checks if all items over are checked and if so, do nothing. Does this sound about right, or are there a smarter way i'm not thinking about?

Comment: @Arif Eqbal, if 1 & 3 is selected and the up button is pressed, 1 should stay 1 and 3 should become 2.

Comment: As I mentioned it is overcomplicating things so my suggestion is move UP/DOWN in a group, check if first item is already topmost then break out of the code do nothing else.

Comment: @Arif Eqbal, that actually makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Your post and many answers confuse Selected with Checked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in sourceListView.SelectedItems)
{
    if (lvi.Index > 0)
    {
        int index = lvi.Index - 1;
        sourceListView.Items.RemoveAt(lvi.Index);
        sourceListView.Items.Insert(index, lvi);
    }
}
```

Basically just removes the item then inserts it above of where it used to be. The ListView automatically handles reshuffling the items down the order after an insert so no worries.

**Edit:**
The reason the two topmost items swap is that the top item will never move (i.e I haven't implemented a `wrap-around` move. The 2nd item, however, is free to move and thus goes to the top of the list.

To resolve this, you can do 1 of 2 things:

> 1. Implement a wrap-around reshuffle (i.e top item goes to the bottom)
> 2. Prevent any movement if the top item is selected (check listview.Items[0].Selected)

As for the re-doing of the text, just do it in the original loop.

Implementation with wraparound:

```
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in sourceListView.SelectedItems)
{
    int index = lvi.Index > 0 ? lvi.Index - 1 : sourceListView.Items.Count - 1;
    sourceListView.Items.RemoveAt(lvi.Index);
    sourceListView.Items.Insert(index, lvi);

    if (index != sourceListView.Items.Count - 1) //not a wraparound:
    {
        //just swap the indices over.
        sourceListView.Items[index + 1].SubItems[1].Text = (index + 1).ToString();
        lvi.SubItems[1].Text = index.ToString();
    }
    else //item wrapped around, have to manually update all items.
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi2 in sourceListView.Items)
            lvi2.SubItems[1].Text = lvi2.Index.ToString();
    }
}
```

#### Edit 2:

Static helper implementation, no wrap-around:

```
private enum MoveDirection { Up = -1, Down = 1 };

private static void MoveListViewItems(ListView sender, MoveDirection direction)
{
    int dir = (int)direction;
    int opp = dir * -1;

    bool valid = sender.SelectedItems.Count > 0 &&
                    ((direction == MoveDirection.Down && (sender.SelectedItems[sender.SelectedItems.Count - 1].Index < sender.Items.Count - 1))
                || (direction == MoveDirection.Up && (sender.SelectedItems[0].Index > 0)));

    if (valid)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in sender.SelectedItems)
        {
            int index = item.Index + dir;
            sender.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
            sender.Items.Insert(index, item);

            sender.Items[index + opp].SubItems[1].Text = (index + opp).ToString();
            item.SubItems[1].Text = (index).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
MoveListViewItems(sourceListView, MoveDirection.Up);
MoveListviewItems(sourceListview, MoveDirection.Down);
```

Comment: Consider using BeginUpdate and EndUpdate to prevent any flickering for something like this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx

Comment: Implementation is really up to the asker's discretion, but it's a valid point.

Comment: I have edited my top post. I tried to solve the problem with items switching places as i described in my edit, but i end up with pretty much the same code as in my original question. Any ideas?

Comment: I have made a second edit, i'm getting closer to a working solution, but i still have problems.

Comment: @Jason Larke, thanks for your time, i really appreciate it. Your static variant has the same problem i encountered earlier, moving two or more items that follow each other (such as 3 & 4) downwards does not work. If they are separated (such as 3 & 5) it works fine. Upwards movement works fine for all cases. Any idea on how i can solve this?

Comment: Yeah, don't use a `foreach`, it's forward-only. You'll have to navigate using indices `for(int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)` etc

Comment: eDIT2: static Helper - much better use a Stack. This solves the bug about "adjacent items don't move"

Comment: Concerning Edit2: Why are you  introducing this variable ```int opp = dir * -1;``` when simply you could use ```index - dir``` instead of ```index + opp```. What does opp mean? Btw. the change of index of ```Items``` in the background is working, but the display doesnt catch up. I work around by just switching the (Text) properties of the items.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the @Jason Larkes answer to make it support "move down" properly, add this right before the foreach in the MoveListViewItems function he provided:

```
ListViewItem[] itemsToBeMoved = sender.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToArray<ListViewItem>(); 
IEnumerable<ListViewItem> itemsToBeMovedEnum;
if (direction == MoveDirection.Down)
     itemsToBeMovedEnum = itemsToBeMoved.Reverse();
else
     itemsToBeMovedEnum = itemsToBeMoved;
```

and then iterate using:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in itemsTobemovedEnum)
```

instead of the original foreach.

Works like a charm.
@EClaesson - I hope this overcomes the issue you wrote about in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This one is with wrapping, so if you move item at index 0 down it will come to last position, and if you move last item up it will be first on list:

```
    public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static void MoveUp<T>(this IList<T> list, int index)
        {
            int newPosition = ((index > 0) ? index - 1 : list.Count - 1);
            var old = list[newPosition];
            list[newPosition] = list[index];
            list[index] = old;
        }

        public static void MoveDown<T>(this IList<T> list, int index)
        {
            int newPosition = ((index + 1 < list.Count) ? index + 1 : 0);
            var old = list[newPosition];
            list[newPosition] = list[index];
            list[index] = old;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Code with wrap around:

```
    private enum MoveDirection { Up = -1, Down = 1 };

    private void MoveListViewItems(ListView sourceListView, MoveDirection direction)
    {
        int dir = (int)direction;

        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in sourceListView.SelectedItems)
        {
            int index = lvi.Index + dir;
            if(index >= sourceListView.Items.Count)
                index = 0;
            else if(index < 0)
                index = sourceListView.Items.Count + dir;

            sourceListView.Items.RemoveAt(lvi.Index);
            sourceListView.Items.Insert(index, lvi);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Short, sweet and a bug: Adjecent items won't move down. Fix: `var sels = sourceListView.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList(); if (direction == MoveDirection.Down) sels.Reverse(); foreach (ListViewItem lvi in sels)....` - To remove the wraparound insert `if ((sels.First().Index == 0 && direction == MoveDirection.Up)
                || (sels.Last().Index >= sourceListView.Items.Count - 1 && direction == MoveDirection.Down)) return;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void MoveItems(ListView sender, MoveDirection direction)
    {
        bool valid = sender.SelectedItems.Count > 0 &&
                    ((direction == MoveDirection.Down && (sender.SelectedItems[sender.SelectedItems.Count - 1].Index < sender.Items.Count - 1))
                    || (direction == MoveDirection.Up && (sender.SelectedItems[0].Index > 0)));

        if (valid)
        {                
            bool start = true;
            int first_idx = 0;                
            List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItem>();

            // ambil data
            foreach (ListViewItem i in sender.SelectedItems)
            {
                if (start)
                {
                    first_idx = i.Index;
                    start = false;
                }
                items.Add(i);
            }

            sender.BeginUpdate();

            // hapus
            foreach (ListViewItem i in sender.SelectedItems) i.Remove();

            // insert
            if (direction == MoveDirection.Up)
            {
                int insert_to = first_idx - 1;
                foreach (ListViewItem i in items)
                {
                    sender.Items.Insert(insert_to, i);
                    insert_to++;
                }                    
            }
            else
            {
                int insert_to = first_idx + 1;
                foreach (ListViewItem i in items)
                {
                    sender.Items.Insert(insert_to, i);
                    insert_to++;
                }   
            }                
            sender.EndUpdate();
        }            
    }
```

> Your answers don't work well fren. Here my code work perfect...

Answer (score 0):

Only for complete, based on 'Jason Larke' static helper solution:

That solution don't move adjacent items, that can be done using a Stack so:

```
private enum MoveDirection { Up = -1, Down = 1 };

private static void MoveListViewItems(ListView sender, MoveDirection direction)
{
int dir = (int)direction;
int opp = dir * -1;

bool valid = sender.SelectedItems.Count > 0 &&
                ((direction == MoveDirection.Down && (sender.SelectedItems[sender.SelectedItems.Count - 1].Index < sender.Items.Count - 1))
            || (direction == MoveDirection.Up && (sender.SelectedItems[0].Index > 0)));

if (valid)
{

Stack aPila = new Stack();
ListViewItem item = default(ListViewItem);
foreach ( item in sender.SelectedItems) {
    aPila.Push(item);
}

for (int iaux = 1; iaux <= aPila.Count; iaux++) {
    {
    item  = (ListViewItem)aPila.Pop();
        int index = item.Index + dir;
        sender.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        sender.Items.Insert(index, item);

        sender.Items[index + opp].SubItems[1].Text = (index + opp).ToString();
        item.SubItems[1].Text = (index).ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum MoveDirection { Up = -1, Down = 1 };

public static void MoveListViewItems(this ListView sender, MoveDirection direction)
{
    if (sender.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && ((direction == MoveDirection.Down && (sender.SelectedItems[sender.SelectedItems.Count - 1].Index < sender.Items.Count - 1))
                                        || (direction == MoveDirection.Up && (sender.SelectedItems[0].Index > 0))))
    {
        List<ListViewItem> llvi = sender.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in direction == MoveDirection.Up ? llvi : llvi.Reverse<ListViewItem>())
        {
            int index = item.Index + (int)direction;
            sender.Items.RemoveAt(item.Index);
            sender.Items.Insert(index, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in a static helper class. It works perfectly for multiple moves up & down. If you want to go down your list must be reversed.